# How Install NGINX + Varnish 6.1.0 with SSL on Ubuntu 18.04???

Tags: ssl, nginx, varnish

I'm using VPS in Digital Ocean and I wanna install varnish 6.1.0 with SSL + NGINX in Ubuntu 18.04 and install PHP 7.2

But I don't know if this Varnish version is compatible with ubuntu 18.04 version in SSL and I don't know how install and setting this.

Please, can help me? ( Please sorry my english )

Answer (score 0):

6.1 isn't an LTS version, I would recommend 6.0, it's in the packagecloud repo: https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60

Varnish doesn't handle SSL itself, so you can indeed use NGINX to terminate SSL, but I would personally go for hitch. For documentation, you can use this: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/features/client-ssl/ , just install `hitch` instead of `varnish-plus-addon-ssl`.

Also, your english is fine, don't worry about it :-)